# Sent mail getting blocked by spam filters

Tags: centos, postfix, webmin

I have just setup a VPS with CentOS and Webmin. I am attempting to setup my email server. I can successfully send mail, however it always gets blocked by spam filters. What steps are needed to make sure it does not get blocked?

```
Domain: HostAxel.com or MafiaStreetWars.com
OS: CentOS
Setup method: VirtualMin & Webmin
Server Type: Postfix
```

On a seprate note.. I cannot receive email either. I don't know if this is a related issue or not.

I got this as a reply from a hotmail address:

```
host mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.37.120] said: 550
    SC-001 (COL0-MC4-F32) Unfortunately, messages from 199.168.139.80 weren't
    sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their
    network is on our block list. You can also refer your provider to
    http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL
    FROM command)
```

Comment: I am not sure how we can help you if the ip address your assigned is flagged as sender of spam.

Answer (score 3):

What is your ISP/web-host ?

Since they are on Hotmail's block list, you will not be able to use your Hotmail account to send or receive emails while connected through your ISP.

You could bring this to the attention of your ISP. They may already know about it, but maybe not. Send them a copy of the error message you got from the bounced email from Hotmail as it may help them when they contact Hotmail to resolve the issue.

Comment: I am using VolumeDrive's VPS. after doing some research I have found out they have whats called the "Internet Death Penalty"